# How to change TOC depth in R Bookdown (GitBook)?

Tags: r, bookdown, gitbook

I use *GitBook* format through *R* *bookdown*. I need to use at least four levels in the table of contents (TOC). The default is three. How can I change the depth of TOC?

---

UPDATE

Now the toc-related contents of my `_output.yml` file look like this:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  config:
    toc_depth: 4
    toc:
      collapse: section
      scroll_highlight: yes
      before: |
        <li><a href="../index.html"><b>Main</b></a></li>
      after: |
        <li><a href="../index.html"><b>Main</b></a></li>
```

`config: toc_depth: 4` does not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `_output.yml` file:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
    toc_depth: 2
```